# ¿Cómo usar las plantillas de un Archivo en otro Archivo en c++?

Tags: c++

Tengo un archivo con extensión **A.cpp** el cual tiene plantillas  que quisiera usar en el archivo **B.cpp**.
Intenté poner lo siguiente en **B.cpp**:

```
#include "A.cpp"
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error:

```
C:\Users\friky\Documents\Octavo Semestre\Inteligencia Artificial\Arbol.cpp  In function 'int main(int, char**)':
3   5   C:\Users\friky\Documents\Octavo Semestre\Inteligencia Artificial\Arbol.cpp  [Error] redefinition of 'int main(int, char**)'
1   0   C:\Users\friky\Documents\Octavo Semestre\Inteligencia Artificial\Arbol.cpp  In file included from C:\Users\friky\Documents\Octavo Semestre\Inteligencia Artificial\Arbol.cpp
286 5   C:\Users\friky\Documents\Octavo Semestre\Inteligencia Artificial\arbolABB-templ.cpp [Error] 'int main(int, char**)' previously defined here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que es porque al incluir el archivo "A.cpp" hay una ambigüedad entre las funciones "main" de cada uno.

Te recomiendo meter lo que quieras usar en esos dos archivos en un fichero "Plantillas.h" e importarlo en ambos.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Un Saludo.

Comment: Gracias, sí me ha sido de ayuda. Aunque en este caso copie el código en **Plantilla.hpp**  ya que si lo hacía en **Plantilla.h** me marcaba error.